# How to use cordova to deal with downloaded plugin folder in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm an iOS developer, now I want to use cordova to develop web. I know how to use the cordova when the www folder is in the bundle. However, I want to download the www folder from the remote server into the local sandbox(for example, /Documents). Now I'm miss.

I tried to open the html file as follow:

```
CDVViewController *controller = [[CDVViewController alloc] init];
controller.wwwFolderName = @"file://~/Documents/www";
controller.startPage = @"index.html";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

but it doesn't work correctly. It seems that it calls the js function(i add a alert() call in the page), but the html content isn't showed.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Cordova as a component in your iOS applications. This component is code-named "Cleaver".

if u want to use in your native to show index.html you need to use cordova webview

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html